# reading a bitmap from a memory mapped file is slower than directly from disk

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have a different process that will generate a lot of bitmaps (eventually it will simulate a video) and I want it displayed on a C# app.

I thought that delivering the bitmaps in a memory mapped file is the fastest way. When I ran the following code I found out that constructing a Bitmap directly from disk is faster.

```
    int length = 153718;
    var mmf1 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"C:\tests\test.bmp",
                                               FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                               null);
    var reader = mmf1.CreateViewAccessor(0, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    stopwatch.Start();

    reader.ReadArray<byte>(0, buffer, 0, length);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(memstream);

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
        stopwatch.Elapsed);

    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();

    Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(@"C:\tests\test2.bmp");

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
        stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

The result is:

> Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0074231
>   Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0023245

I timed only the recurring code that will run (not including the setup)
Both bitmaps are the same image, rather small 640*480 bmp.

How is it possible? Is there a more efficient memory mapped way?

Comment: Your first read of the file will put its pages in the filesystem cache. The second read will only have to read from cache.

Comment: I tried it in a loop (1000 times) - still the first one is ~3 times slower

Comment: _I thought that delivering the bitmaps in a memory mapped file is the fastest way._ Why do/did you think that? MMF is sometimes better for random access but for sequential access a simple file is probably better optimized.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I thought that the overhead of opening and closing of a file, trying to do it a lot (remember - those bitmaps will be a video) - will be big, wanted to make sure I'm not missing something...

Comment: Then make a better benchmark (opening 1 MMF vs multiple files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not surprising. Making a memory stream from an array read from a memory mapped file adds extra layers that the data has to pass through.

The memory mapped file acts as a layer between the file and view accessor, providing random access to a file. You are not using this capability as you are reading all the data at once, so reading the data directly from the file into the array would be faster than reading it from a memory mapped file.

The memory stream acts as another layer between the array and the stream reading from it. Basically it copies all the data through another buffer before delivering it to the Bitmap object.